# Django - How to use django.contrib.humanize?

Tags: django

I have used the given function to get the table's data, and to check if the value is negative, so highlight it. Now I have used django's `humanize` to make the numeric figures easier to read. But this piece of code isn;t executed.

```
var formatBackground=function(){
    tdArray=document.getElementsByTagName('td');
    for(l=0; l<=tdArray.length-1;l++){
        val = tdArray[l].innerHTML;
        if(!isNaN(parseFloat(val)) && isFinite(val)){
            console.log("INCOMMING VALUE: ",val);
            tdArray[l].innerHTML='{{ val|floatformat:"3"|intcomma }}';//NON EXECUTED LINE OF CODE
            }
        if(Math.abs(parseFloat(val))!== parseFloat(val) && !isNaN(Math.abs(parseFloat(val)))){
            tdArray[l].setAttribute('style','color: red');
            tdArray[l].parentNode.setAttribute('style','background-color: pink');
        }
    }
};
```

Please help me how can I do it?
I have loaded '`{% load humanize %}`'
and also placed `'django.contrib.humanize'` in my `INSTALLED_APPS`, in `settings.py`

Comment: What does your favorite html/javascript debugger say to this?

Comment: is this in a js file or in a django template ?

Comment: möter-- It doesn't print any exception, just passes through it, without showing any error.

Comment: karthikr-- its in django template

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This can't work. You seem to have failed to understand the difference between server-side template code and client-side JavaScript. Template code is fully evaluated on the server side before it is passed to the browser. JS that is triggered by changes to client-side controls cannot possibly evaluate a template tag.

Answer (score 1):

You cannot mix server-side (Django) and client-side (JS) code like this: the entire Django code is executed before sending any content to the browser, at which point the entire JS code is executed.

In your case, you are defining a JS variable `val` (in the browser) and then attempting to format it using Django (before the browser sees it).